# How to get URL in Java using the Remember The Milk API?

Tags: java, android, api

I want to write an Android application that uses the [Remember the Milk API](https://www.rememberthemilk.com/services/api/), but I can't figure out how to use the API's app authentication scheme. How do I generate the URL to authenticate my application with RTM?

Comment: You mean you need to add the API in the project? Is the API using key?

http://www.rememberthemilk.com/login/?return=%2Fservices%2Fapi%2Frequestkey.rtm Here you can obtain API key, if you haven't already

Comment: i have the key already with me,but i don't know the process of getting authenticated. i have seen the methods in the API but,couldn't understand what to do with.Am new to this,please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking for this too, and seems it was right in front of me. https://www.rememberthemilk.com/services/api/request.rest.rtm is where it explains the format.

Basically it's https://api.rememberthemilk.com/services/rest/ and then whatever you want to send.

So it would seem you'd start by getting the frob using https://api.rememberthemilk.com/services/rest/?method=rtm.auth.getFrob&api_key=123456789

Then when you get the frob back you'd use it to get a token with https://api.rememberthemilk.com/services/rest/?method=rtm.auth.getToken&api_key=123456789&frob=0a56717c3561e53584f292bb7081a533c197270c

Of course you'd replace that random key and frob with your actual key and whatever you get back from getFrob.

I'm about to try using this myself, so I'll try and post back if anything needs to be changed.